# Add 'onclick' attribute to a button in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

I have a button that looks like this

```
 <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" id="savebtn"/>
```

And a javascript function that looks like this

```
   function OnChangeEvent(event) {
        //Call some controller function here and do your increase/decrease logic and return value so we know what to do. also perform your save in controller too if needed.
        var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
        alert("value is changed from " + @Model.comp_qty + " to" + compQty);
        //do other functions here also like change button
        //if decrease add below
        if (compQty < @Model.comp_qty) {
            savebtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clicked(event)");
        }
    }
```

I want to add the attributes to the button if the condition is successful
Here is my 'Onclick' function'

```
  function clicked(e) {

            var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
            alert("value is changed from " + @Model.comp_qty + " to" + compQty);
  }
```

But the function isn't being run which I assume means the attributes aren't properly being added. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: compQty input filed or what?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you define the compQTY id. is this input filed or span like ?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are saying. If the condition is successful I basically want the button to be changed to this '<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" onclick = "clicked(event)" id="savebtn"/>'  But currently it is not adding the attributes that should be assigned to it from the onchange.

Comment: can you check in debugger mode. you can identify if function is call or not

Comment: @Dev It has issues with the addAttributes line. If I put before the alert. The alert wont work.

Comment: try this - $('#savebtn').attr("onclick", "clicked(event)");

Comment: @Dev Yes! Thank-you that worked